# Include .js file in All Gsp file in STS (Eclipse) IDE?

Tags: eclipse, grails, gsp, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

is there any way to include a file in all gsp file header ? i want to include a file

```
<g:javascript src="hotkey.js"/>
```

in all Gsp files heade part. i'm using STS (SpringSource Tool Suite).

Comment: This is more a question about grails than it is about STS.  I added a grails tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include your .js files in main.gsp then it will automatically be included in all gsps with the tag `<meta name="layout" content="main" />` in the `<head>`. Example gsp head below:

```
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'transactionRecord.label', default: 'TransactionRecord')}" />
    <title><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
</head>
```

The main layout is automatically included in all gsps generated by the scaffolding create commands.